# Display file content in tabular format after clicking a link

Tags: jsp

```
 File root = new File("C:\\");
    FilenameFilter beginswithm = new FilenameFilter()
    {
     public boolean accept(File directory, String filename) {
          return filename.startsWith("R");
      }
    };

    File[] files = root.listFiles(beginswithm);
    for (File f: files)
    {
      fileName1=f.getName();
    }
```

I am using the above code to get a list of files whose name starts with R. How can I display it as a list of links in JSP and let each link show the file's content in a new window?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Are you *somewhat* familiar with HTML/JSP/Servlets? Have you already worked through some basic tutorials such as the ones at oracle.com and coreservlets.com?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add few lines to this code

```
for (File f: files)
{
  fileName1=f.getName();
}
```

to

```
<%
    for (File f: files)
    {
      fileName1=f.getName();
%>
<a href="<%=fileName1%>" target="_blank"><%=fileName1%></a>
<%
    }
%>
```